# MySQL 5.5 innodb_large_prefix configuration setting not taking effect

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm running MySQL 5.5.55 on Debian Linux and I would like to enable the `innodb_large_prefix` setting so I can have table INDEXes that are larger than 767 bytes.

I have the following configuration in my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
...
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb-large-prefix=ON
innodb_file_format=barracuda
```

(I've also tried `innodb_large_prefix=ON` as well.)

UPDATE: I double-checked, and no other configuration files exist e.g. `/etc/my.cnf`, `/usr/etc/my.cnf`, `~root/.my.cnf`, `~mysql/.my.cnf`)

But when I restart MySQL, the active configuration shows as:

```
| innodb_file_format             | Barracuda              |
| innodb_large_prefix            | OFF                    |
| innodb_file_per_table          | ON                     |
```

If I manually change the GLOBAL setting from the MySQL CLI, the setting appears to change:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix = ON;
...
| innodb_large_prefix            | ON                     |
```

...but then when I attempt to actually use a "large prefix", I get an error:

```
mysql> alter table [...]
ERROR 1709 (HY000): Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.
```

The documentation for MySQL's [`innodb_large_prefix` setting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix) says that there are several prerequisites to use this setting:

1. MySQL version 5.5.14 or later ✔
2. `innodb_file_format` = `Barracuda` ✔
3. `innodb_file_per_table` = `ON` ✔
4. `innodb_large_prefix` = `ON` ✔

After playing-around a little bit, I was able to convert my table as desired by doing:

1. `SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix = ON;`
2. `ALTER TABLE [...], ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;`

Great. Then I restarted MySQL again and checked the effective settings:

```
| innodb_large_prefix            | OFF                    |
```

I have no errors when using that table, etc. so I guess everything is okay, but it's strange that the setting doesn't seem to stick.

I tried re-ALTERing my table with the setting set to `OFF` and I am unable to build that large index. Does this mean that I will have to manually set the `innodb_large_prefix` to `ON` any time I want to ALTER a table in this way? Am I not configuring this setting properly in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`?

Comment: Thank goodness 5.7 finally defaulted things so that all this junk is no longer needed.

Answer (score 6):

It's a little bit hidden, but according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/dynamic-system-variables.html), for MySQL < 5.6, you have to use `1` instead of `ON` in the config file:

> Variables that have a type of “boolean” can be set to 0, 1, ON or OFF. (If you set them on the command line or in an option file, use the numeric values.)

For MySQL >= 5.6, you are allowed to use `ON` and `OFF` [in the config files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/dynamic-system-variables.html).

Comment: Confirmed that `ON` does not work but `1` does... *and* that MySQL 5.6 allows either. You'd think that because MySQL will allow you to use any unique prefix for a configuration setting to set that variable would allow any reasonable "spelling" of a boolean value in the configuration file.